# Spring caching with JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

I am trying to cache some of the DAO calls to improve my performance with spring cache But its not working for me. Please find the code below what i have tried

Main class:

```
        @SpringBootApplication
        @EnableCaching
        @EnableAutoConfiguration
        public class Test{

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
            }

        }
```

### Service class:

```
    @Transactional
    @Service
    public class ProjectService{

    @Cacheable("project")
        public Project validateProject(String resource) {

            Project project = projRepo.findByName(resource.trim());
            System.out.println("ProjectCache called");

            if (project != null) {
                return project;
            } else {
                project = new Project();
                project.setName(resource);
                return project;
            }

        }

    }
```

DAO class

```
    @Repository
    public interface IProjectRepository extends BaseRepository<Project> {

        Project findByName(@Param("projectName") String name);
    }
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode

    public class Project implements Serializable, ICommonEntity {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        private Integer           id;

        private String            name;
}
```

Build.gradle

```
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:2.2.0.RELEASE
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version:'2.2.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: "2.0.4.RELEASE"
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache', version: '2.2.0.RELEASE'
```

its always printing "ProjectCache called" in console ;

Please some one help me on this

Comment: You need to add spring-context or spring-context-support dependency as well

Comment: @Ravik after adding that also its not working

Comment: do you call `validateProject(String resource) {` in the same class?

Comment: can you also code where you are calling  **validateProject** of  **ProjectService**

Comment: @PrashanthS So work any of the annotation, it must be passsed through proxy, in case, where if you call same method of the class, it won't go through proxy and annotation processor won't come into picture to process any annotation, be it Cachable/Custom Annotation or anything.

Comment: i am calling validateProject  inside ProjectService only . I moved that different service its started of working fine Thanks guys